# Programmatically populating data in Property Set Definitions assigned to objects

Tags: c#, autocad, autodesk-forge, autocad-plugin, autodesk-designautomation

I'm writing an AutoCAD (MEP?) plugin that needs to populate a Property Set Data that has been assigned to objects.

I have the Entity Handle of the objects and the data to assign, but I cannot find any documentation on how to programmatically insert data into a Property Set Definition, or how to programmatically pick/determine the Property Set Definition. This documentation seems to be completely missing from the API.

I can do it in the UI, by hand, but I'm looking for something where I can use the Forge Design Automation API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't yet have support for non-AutoCAD references or commands.

Comment: Feel free to let me know when that changes. In the meantime I'll develop an Add-In for AutoCAD MEP Instead, thanks.